# Concatenate field data with previous and next rows

Tags: t-sql, sql-server-2008-r2

I want to concatenate a field with previous and next rows. for example if I have this:

```
|ID|word|
|0 |Hi! |
|1 |How |
|2 |Are |
|3 |You |
```

I want to create a stored procedure with to input, 'before' and 'after' which indicate how many rows should use for previous and next of current row.
for example if we have before=1 and after=1 then we'll get this

```
|ID|word       |
|0 |Hi! How    |
|1 |Hi! How Are|
|2 |How Are You|
|3 |Are You    |
```

and if we have before=2 and after=1 then we'll get this

```
|ID|word           |
|0 |Hi! How        |
|1 |Hi! How Are    |
|2 |Hi! How Are You|
|3 |How Are You    |
```

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check this:
    DECLARE @before TINYINT = 2
    DECLARE @after TINYINT = 1

```
SELECT  ISNULL(( SELECT STUFF((SELECT   ISNULL(TblBefore.word, '') + ' '
                               FROM     Tbl TblBefore
                               WHERE    TblBefore.Id BETWEEN T.Id - @before AND T.Id
                                        - 1
                        FOR   XML PATH('') ,
                                  TYPE).value('.', 'varchar(max)'), 1, 0, '') AS ChildValues
               ), '') + T.Word + ' '
        + ISNULL(( SELECT   STUFF((SELECT   ISNULL(TblBefore.word, '') + ' '
                                   FROM     Tbl TblBefore
                                   WHERE    TblBefore.Id BETWEEN T.Id + 1 AND T.Id
                                            + @after
                            FOR   XML PATH('') ,
                                      TYPE).value('.', 'varchar(max)'), 1, 0,
                                  '') AS ChildValues
                 ), '')
FROM  Tbl T
```

Comment: Awesome. Thanks a lot. You really help me. But there are some characters in my data that cant use in XML and I got this error. could you please help me? FOR XML could not serialize the data for node 'NoName' because it contains a character (0x0016) which is not allowed in XML. To retrieve this data using FOR XML, convert it to binary, varbinary or image data type and use the BINARY BASE64 directive.

Answer (score 0):

SELECT  Columnname + ' ' + (
        SELECT  TOP 1 Myt2.Columnname
        FROM    table1 Myt2
        WHERE   Myt2.ColumnID < t1.ColumnID
        ORDER BY 
                ColumnID
        )
FROM table1 Myt1
ORDER BY
      Myt1.ColumnID

This code snippet works for 2 levels...:) still not the complete answer. It may help to get you to nth level.